# Was soll ich nach "in" benutzen: Dativ oder Akkusativ?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Ich weiß nicht welchen Fall ich benutzen soll. Manchmal sehe ich es mit Dativ

> Ich bin in der Küche.

aber manchmal ich sehe es auch mit Akkusativ. Kann mir das bitte jemand erklären?

Comment: Vom Namen schließe ich auf einen spanischen Muttersprachler. Deberías associar donde/adonde = wo/wohin a in+Dativ/in+Akkusativ.

Answer (score 15):

**In die Küche** (Akkusativ) beschreibt eine *Bewegung in den Raum hinein*; **"in der Küche"** (Dativ) beschreibt eine *Position* eines Objektes, das sich bereits *im Raum* befindet.

Comment: danke vielmals, ich habe diesen Zweifel jedes mal ;D

Answer (score 6):

Das Verb *sein* mit der Präposition *in* verlangt - wenn es als Ortsangabe verwendet wird - den Dativ.

> Ich bin in der Küche.

Akkusativ wäre hier falsch: *Ich bin in die Küche.*

Der Dativ gibt bei Verben den aktuellen Ort an, während der Akkusativ für die Richtung auf ein Ziel verwendet wird. Beispiel: *Ich gehe in die Küche.*