# Wieso ist es "unseren" und nicht "unserem"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Wieso ist in dem folgendem Satz:

> Laufen hat viele positive Effekte auf unseren Körper.

**unseren** und nicht **unserem** ??

Comment: Related, but for a different preposition: [Was soll ich nach “in” benutzen: Dativ oder Akkusativ?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1532/1224)

Comment: Selbe Antwort: Ich gehe in DIE Garage, dann bin ich in DER Garage. Ich verirre mich in DAS Hafenviertel (ich gerate von woanders dorthin), oder ich verirre mich iM Hafenviertel (ich wollte im Hafenviertel zu einem bestimmten Punkt und bin dabei vom Weg abgekommen). Ich klettere auf EINEN Baum vom Boden aus oder klettere auf EINEM Baum von einem Ast zum anderen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*auf* mit **Dativ** zeigt einen **Ort** an, man fragt danach mit *wo?*:

> Auf unsere**m** Körper befinden sich unzählige kleine Härchen (wo?)
>
> Auf de**m** Dach sitzt eine Katze (wo?)
>
> Ich bin auf de**m** Fest (wo?)

*auf* mit **Akkusativ** zeigt eine **Richtung** an, man fragt danach mit *wohin?*, *worauf?* usw.:

> Laufen hat positive Effekte auf unsere**n** Körper (worauf?)
>
> Gestern ging ich auf de**n** Berg (wohin?)
>
> Gehst du mit auf **das** Fest? (wohin?)

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Deutsch unterscheidet sehr genau zwischen Position und Bewegung. Englisch hat diese genaue Unterscheidung meistens nicht, macht aber in einigen Fällen doch einen Unterschied.

1 Das Buch liegt auf dem Tisch. - Wo? auf + Dativ.

2 Lege das Buch auf das Tischchen da in der Ecke. - Wohin? auf + Akkusativ.

Bei "Effekt/Wirkung auf etwas (Akk)" hat man das Modell *Bewegung* im Sinn. Es ist nicht das Modell *Position*: Der Effekt/die Wirkung befindet/liegt/ist nicht "auf dem Ķörper".

Deswegen auch beim Verb "wirken auf etwas (Akk)": Die Bremsen wirken auf die Räder.